# Adding barcode to sato printer label

Tags: vb6, thermal-printer

I am using VB6 to create barcode for code 39, upc and ean 13 with sato cx using sbl language. I am not sure what code to use, I create a barcode but reader does not read it.

My code:

```
SASTextoBarra = Chr$(27) & "H00780" & Chr$(27) & "V1000" & _
Chr$(27) & " H0030 " & Chr$(27) & "V0240" & Chr$(27) & "B103100*CODE 39*"

SASTextoBarra = SASTextoBarra & Chr$(27) & "H00380" & Chr$(27) & "B103100*12345*"
```

I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple text printer to your Sato Cx (generic printer) linked to lpt1
With VB create a text file (printout.txt)

```
open "c:\printout.txt" for output as #1
```

write the following lines

```
print #1,"<A>"
print #1,"<V>1000<H>30<B>10310012345"
print #1,"<Z>"
close #1
```

now send the printout.txt file to lpt1
you can do that by shell execute

```
type printout.txt >lpt1:
```

or create a send2printer.bat file and call it through VB

Comment: I have another problem i can not read and print code like 024792, C00008 with code 39 or upc. any help?